# NSFetchedResultsController sort different sections differently (ascending/descending)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sorting, core-data

In my app, I have a task list (no, it's not just another todo app), and I display the tasks in a `UITableView` using an `NSFetchedResultsController`. Here is the relevant initialisation code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *dueDateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"due" YES];
NSSortDescriptor *completionSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"completed" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:completionSortDescriptor, dueDateSortDescriptor, nil]];

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"completed" cacheName:nil];
```

What this does is sorts the tasks such that I have an incomplete tasks section at the top, sorting with the tasks due first on top, and tasks due later further down. This all works.

**However**, this means that the second section, the one with the completed tasks, also sorts this way, so the earliest due tasks are on top. What I want to do is change it so the second section sorts the other way around (in descending order), but the first section stays sorted in ascending order. Is this even possible? How would I go about this?

**Why I want to do this:** The way it currently works, the tasks at the top of the second section (and therefore the most visible) are the ones that were completed ages ago. It is more likely that the user would want to see the tasks that are more recently completed (and uncheck one if it was accidentally checked), and presumably the tasks with a more recent due date were more recently completed. I am happy to add a separate completion date field to the Core Data task object if necessary (This isn't a shipping application yet, so I can change the data format however I like).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>This is not possible when using an NSFetchedResultsController. You'd have to manually fetch your data and implement UITableView's delegate methods.</strike>

**EDIT**: Whoah, my mistake, there's a fairly easy solution for this. Set two sort descriptors:

- The first one for `completedDate` (descending). This field is the same (`nil`) for all incomplete tasks.
- Add a second one for `addedDate` (ascending). It will sort by completed date (newest first), but in the first section you won't have any completedDates, so it will then use the added date (oldest first).

For the second section, it will just use `completedDate` (newest first), so there you go.

Comment: Thanks ;)
I'll get onto this next and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much!
I did also have to add a sort descriptor for completion status and put that first, because without it the completed tasks appeared above the incomplete tasks (sometimes).

But, everything works now, so thanks again ;)

Comment: Without seeing specific data I can't really tell how that happens, but a tip (for you, or someone who finds this thread later): make the completion status field a transient field (meaning it won't be stored in your database), and then create an accessor method in your NSManagedObject subclass (assuming you have one) in which you read the completion date. That way, you don't have to update two fields (with the possibility of forgetting one) when you update a task to be completed.

Comment: What I'm doing now is overriding `didChangeValueForKey:` in the `NSManagedObject` subclass and checking for modification of the `completed` property (because I already have a lot of code written that changes the boolean directly, and I can't be bothered to change it), and sets the `completedDate` to the current date or `nil`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that works too. As long as updating one field also automatically updates the other field so that you as a programmer don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Pretty much. And for me, making the fields update each other is currently easier than going through something like 10 very long source files and fixing it in all of them.